# Name error: name "apply" is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following error when I push the scroll down on the multilistbox. Hope you can help me:

```
  File "...", line 44, in _scroll
    apply(l.yview, args)
Name error: name "apply" is not defined
```

This is my code

```
from tkinter import *

class MultiListbox(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, lists):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lists = []
        for l,w in lists:
            frame = Frame(self); frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            Label(frame, text=l, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
            lb = Listbox(frame, width=w, borderwidth=0, selectborderwidth=0,
                 relief=FLAT, exportselection=FALSE)
            lb.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
            self.lists.append(lb)
            lb.bind('<B1-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e, s=self: s._select(e.y))
            lb.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: 'break')
            lb.bind('<B2-Motion>', lambda e, s=self: s._b2motion(e.x, e.y))
            lb.bind('<Button-2>', lambda e, s=self: s._button2(e.x, e.y))
        frame = Frame(self); frame.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        Label(frame, borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
        sb = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self._scroll)
        sb.pack(expand=YES, fill=Y)

    def yview(self, *args):
        """connect the yview action together"""
        self.lb1.yview(*args)
        self.lb2.yview(*args)

    def _select(self, y):
        row = self.lists[0].nearest(y)
        self.selection_clear(0, END)
        self.selection_set(row)
        return 'break'

    def _button2(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_mark(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _b2motion(self, x, y):
        for l in self.lists: l.scan_dragto(x, y)
        return 'break'

    def _scroll(self, *args):
        for l in self.lists:
            apply(l.yview, args)

    def curselection(self):
        return self.lists[0].curselection()

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.delete(first, last)

    def get(self, first, last=None):
        result = []
        for l in self.lists:
            result.append(l.get(first,last))
        if last: return apply(map, [None] + result)
        return result

    def index(self, index):
        self.lists[0].index(index)

    def insert(self, index, *elements):
        for e in elements:
                i = 0
        for l in self.lists:
            l.insert(index, e[i])
            i = i + 1

    def size(self):
        return self.lists[0].size()

    def see(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.see(index)

    def selection_anchor(self, index):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_anchor(index)

    def selection_clear(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_clear(first, last)

    def selection_includes(self, index):
        return self.lists[0].selection_includes(index)

    def selection_set(self, first, last=None):
        for l in self.lists:
            l.selection_set(first, last)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tk = Tk()
    Label(tk, text='MultiListbox').pack()
    mlb = MultiListbox(tk, (('Clave', 20), ('Descripcion', 20), ('Existencia', 20)))

    lineas = len(open("productos-doc1.txt").readlines())
    totalLineas=(int(lineas))

    try:
        x = 0
        while 0 != totalLineas:
            abrir = open("productos-doc1.txt","r+")#ABRE EL ARCHIVO
            leer = abrir.readlines()
            renglon = leer[x]
            splitRenglon = renglon.split("'")
            clave = splitRenglon[0]
            descripcion = splitRenglon[1]
            existencia = splitRenglon[3]
            mlb.insert(END, (clave, descripcion, existencia))
            mlb.pack(expand=YES,fill=BOTH)

            x = x+1
    except IndexError:
        mlb.insert(END,"FINISH" )

    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to use a function from Python 2 in Python 3. The Python 2 [`apply()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) was already deprecated, removed completely from Python 3 and shouldn't be used in Python 2 either. From the documentation:

> *Deprecated since version 2.3*: Use `function(*args, **keywords)` instead of `apply(function, args, keywords)` (see [*Unpacking Argument Lists*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments)).

Use `*args` instead:

```
l.yview(*args)
```

and

```
if last: return map(None, *result)
```

Comment: Done! Have another question. When I use the mouse wheel, all the columns moves independently (up or down) how can I move simultaneously all the columns?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really use tkinter myself; perhaps subject for a new question?